# how do I submit an email from $POST to two websites

Tags: php, email

I have been searching the web for a similar question and have found none, Your help would be greatly appreciated. I have a webpage which takes a user's inputted email address, but i would like to submit it to two different forms, one of which I have no server access to. how should I proceed? I heard that Iframes can be used in this instance, but Im not entirely sure.

Thanks again.

-MDB

Comment: `ajax` to local server and submit to remote serve on success

Comment: Please clarify your question, if your question is "you would like to link to link a different server" then use cURL
----------------------------------
If your question is you would like to pass the inputted value, when the user clicked the submit, then use GET/POST parameter to pass a value and retrieve the value.

Comment: my question is say i have an input box entitled Email. My user goes on the website, inputs his email, and presses submit. Once submitted i want that value (the email address) passed to both my server, and to a server which I have no access to. I understand how to pass it to my own server, but the server which I have no access to, also has an input field for email, and I would like to pass the user's email to this field as well.

Answer (score 0):

The first form:

```
<form name="Sendform" method="post" action="https://aaa.bbb.com/somthing" target="_blank" accept-charset="UTF-8">
<input class="send_input" type="text" name="1" id="1" placeholder="name" />
<img src="/images/sendBTN.png" onclick="Sendform.submit();submitForm();"/>
</form>
//Sendform.submit(); <-- sending it to the action url
//submitForm(); <-- call a js function that will send another email
```

The second one

```
function submitForm()
{
    var first = $("input#1.send_input").val();
    var redirect = 'http://localhost:8088';
    var action = 'http://localhost:8088/wp-login.php?action=register';
    var method = 'post';
    var params = {'first_name':first,'redirect_to':redirect};

    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", action);    
    form.setAttribute("accept-charset","UTF-8");
    form.setAttribute("name", "registerform");
    form.setAttribute("id", "registerform");
    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);          
            hiddenField.setAttribute("id", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);
            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
         }
    }
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();//<-- send the second email
}
```